# Reverse complement of fasta file

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I'm trying to get the reverse complement of RNA in a multi fasta file

input:

```
>cel-mir-39 MI0010 C elegans miR-39
UAUACCGAGAGCCCAGCUGAUUUCGUCUUGGUAAUAAGCUCGUCAUUGAGAUUAUCACCGGGUGUAAAUCAGCUUGGCUCAAAAAAAA

>cel-let-7 MI0001 C elegans let-7
UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAACUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGGGGGGG
```

output:

```
>cel-mir-39 MI0010 C elegans miR-39
UUUUUUUUGAGCCAAGCUGAUUUACACCCGGUGAUAAUCUCAAUGACGAGCUUAUUACCAAGACGAAAUCAGCUGGGCUCUCGGUAUA

>cel-let-7 MI0001 C elegans let-7
CCCCCCCUCCGGUAAGGUAGAAAAUUGCAUAGUUCACCGGUGGUAAUAUUCCAAACUAUACAACCUACUACCUCACCGGAUCCACAGUGUA
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
UUUUUUUUGAGCCAAGCUGAUUUACACCCGGUGAUAAUCUCAAUGACGAGCUUAUUACCAAGACGAAAUCAGCUGGGCUCUCGGUAUA
93-Rim snucele G 0100IM 93-rim-leg 
CCCCCCCUCCGGUAAGGUAGAAAAUUGCAUAGUUCACCGGUGGUAAUAUUCCAAACUAUACAACCUACUACCUCACCGGAUCCACAGUGUA
7-tel snucele G 1000IM 7-tel-leg
```

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "type in the path of the file\n";
my $file_name = <>;
chomp($file_name); 

open (FASTA, $file_name) or die "error #!"; 

$/ = ">";
<FASTA>;    
while (my $entry = <FASTA>){
    $entry = reverse $entry;
    $entry =~ tr/ACGUacgu/UGCAugca/;
    print "$entry \n";
}

close(FASTA);
```

How can I reverse only the sequence and not the header?
Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is related to splitting of records using `$/`, the Perl input record separator. The first call to `<FASTA>` will return all characters up to and including the first `>`. It means that this call simply will return a single `">"` ( and hence it will not skip the header line as you might assume )

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I thought the components of DNA were ACGT, not ACGU — is that a difference of language, or something else?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Adenine, Cytosine and Guanine are present in both DNA and RNA sequences. Thymine occurs only in DNA and Uracil only in RNA. So the DNA bases are ACGT while the RNA bases are ACGU

Comment: @Borodin:  Thanks.  My last biology lessons were a long time ago and may not have covered this difference between DNA and RNA. Or the passage of time let it slip away…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading records separated by `>` is a nice idea as it gives you the whole chunk at a time.  However, here you want to process and merge lines but not the header, thus distinguishing between lines. It is clearer to read line by line.

The sequence-line is specific: all caps and nothing else. The blank line separates records to process. The remaining possibility is the header. The sequence is assembled by joining lines that match its pattern, and once we hit the blank line it is processed and printed.

```
open (FASTA, $file_name) or die "error $!";

# sequence, built by joining lines =~ /^[A-Z]+$/
my $sequence = '';

while (my $entry = <FASTA>)
{
    if ($entry =~ m/^[A-Z]+$/) {
        # Assemble the sequence from separate lines
        chomp($entry);
        $sequence .= $entry;
    }
    elsif ($entry =~ m/^\s*$/) { 
        # process and print the sequence and blank line, reset for next
        $sequence = reverse $sequence;
        $sequence =~ tr/ACGUacgu/UGCAugca/;
        print "$sequence\n";
        print "\n";
        $sequence = '';
    }
    else { # header
        print $entry;
    }
}

# Print the last sequence if the file didn't end with blank line    
if (length $sequence) {
    $sequence = reverse $sequence;
    $sequence =~ tr/ACGUacgu/UGCAugca/;
    print "$sequence\n";
}
```

The `^` and `$` are *anchors*, for the beginning and end of string. So the regex matching the sequence requires that the whole line be strictly caps.  The other regex allows only optional space `\s*`, specifying a blank line.

The sequence processing is copied from the question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  Thank you very much, fixed.  (I had answered "_reverse only the sequence and not the header_", missing the rest for some reason.)

Comment: fixed to work with the example input in the question

Comment: @ysth  Oh, of course, the whole block is processed at once in OP.  (I also realize now I had forgotten to copy the last sequence's print from my code.)  Thank you _very much_ for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) solution:

```
@(bind compl @(hash-from-pairs (zip "ACGUacgu" "UGCAugca")))
@(repeat)
>@header
@  (collect)
@rna
@  (until)

@  (end)
@  (output)
>@header
@(mapcar compl (reverse (cat-str rna)))

@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr revcomp.txr data
>cel-mir-39 MI0010 C elegans miR-39
UUUUUUUUGAGCCAAGCUGAUUUACACCCGGUGAUAAUCUCAAUGACGAGCUUAUUACCAAGACGAAAUCAGCUGGGCUCUCGGUAUA

>cel-let-7 MI0001 C elegans let-7
CCCCCCCUCCGGUAAGGUAGAAAAUUGCAUAGUUCACCGGUGGUAAUAUUCCAAACUAUACAACCUACUACCUCACCGGAUCCACAGUGUA
```

This variant formats the output to 46 columns, like the original:

```
@(bind compl @(hash-from-pairs (zip "ACGUacgu" "UGCAugca")))
@(repeat)
>@header
@  (collect)
@rna
@  (until)

@  (end)
@  (output)
>@header
@  (repeat :vars ((crna (tuples 46 (mapcar compl (reverse (cat-str rna)))))))
@crna
@  (end)

@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr revcomp.txr data
>cel-mir-39 MI0010 C elegans miR-39
UUUUUUUUGAGCCAAGCUGAUUUACACCCGGUGAUAAUCUCAAUGA
CGAGCUUAUUACCAAGACGAAAUCAGCUGGGCUCUCGGUAUA

>cel-let-7 MI0001 C elegans let-7
CCCCCCCUCCGGUAAGGUAGAAAAUUGCAUAGUUCACCGGUGGUAA
UAUUCCAAACUAUACAACCUACUACCUCACCGGAUCCACAGUGUA
```

Comment: When the OP asks about Perl, I'm not sure how useful it is to illustrate an answer with another language that is, at first glance, as cryptic as Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Try something as follow

First I split the data by the newline character. And store the header into the `$header` and the rest of the data in `@ar`.

Then join the array by the newline and store into the `$entry`. Then perform the substitution for to remove the `\n>\r\s` characters from the RNA sequence.

Then as usual reverse the string and perform the translation. Finally get the output by the print statement.

```
open my $fh,"<","filename.text" or die"error opening $!";

$/ = ">";

<$fh>;

while (<$fh>)
{
    my ($header,@ar) = split("\n",$_);

    my $entry =join("\n",@ar);

    $entry=~s/\n|\r|>|\s//g;

    $entry = reverse $entry;

    $entry =~ tr/ACGUacgu/UGCAugca/;

    print ">$header\n$entry\n\n";
}
```

Comment: If you use three parameter split you will save yourself a lot of trouble: `my ($header, $rna) = split("\n",$_, 2)`